# Django Python в веб-разработке

Tags: python, веб-программирование, django

Я сегодня видел фреймворк под названием"Django".Я всегда работал с PHP(новичок). Там обработка форм так далее.Сейчас хочу создать мощный сайт с Python. Искал и увидел Django.Я установил все готово есть некоторые вопросы

- Можно ли создать мощные сайты с Python для обработки форм,данных так далее.
- Что такое Django?
- Я установил Django но не знаю как и откуда начать написать скрипт для сайта.
- Все что забыл спросить можете подсказать? Буду я всем блогадарен!

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/#first-steps

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v8K9x9-hNK4
в этом случае советую потратить час 20 минут на обзор Фреймворков... прежде чем бросаться в Django

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ответ на вопрос 1:**

Да, можно создать все что душе пожелает. Если собираешься использовать Django, то там всё есть. И заодно у тебя многое будет под защитой, так как в Django это все предусмотрено!

**Ответ на вопрос 2:**

Django это веб фреймворк написанный на языке программирования Python. Его можно использовать как для создания совсем простых сайтов так и для создания огромных сервисов, интернет магазинов или же написать свой Инстаграм) Кстати Инстаграм написан на Django :)

**Ответ на 3 вопрос:**

Можно начать с документации, но если у тебя проблемы с английским, то я советую посмотреть вначале вот эти видеоуроки на русском: [Вот ссылочка](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL0lO_mIqDDFXx5_8RmAqAmD_Cdb9DV-H5)

Comment: «Кстати Инстаграм написан на Django» — а есть какое-нибудь подтверждение тому, что инстаграм *до сих пор* работает на джанге?

Comment: Я вас блогадарю все четко и понятно!!

Answer (score 1):

Есть документация к джанге на русском. Но  только до версии 1.9
Я по ней учился. Очень хорошая.

Там есть и уроки для начинающих

https://djbook.ru/rel1.9/

Ещё на джанге работает высоконагруженный сайт варгейминга.